# Unwanted routes appear after reboot

Tags: networking, routing

I installed Debian Jessie on my laptop. I used the ethernet port. I installed the drivers for wifi, and verified that the wifi worked.
I disconnected the ethernet and rebooted the laptop. I indeed had a wifi connection, and could access the router configuration page in my browser, but the routing table had ethernet routes which made internet access impossible.
I removed these routes, and all was well.
Later I rebooted and the routes I had removed had returned. I removed them again but now they return on each reboot.

Where do they come from? It does not seem to be NetworkManager or the /etc/network/ system.

How do I stop this from happenning?

Thanks, Jim

Comment: After some more experimenting, I determined that the routes were added when the ethernet interface (eth0) was brought up. I thought that I had disabled that by removing 'auto eth0' from /etc/network/interfaces.I also needed to remove 'allow-hotplug eth0'.

Comment: Please take your comment and write it as an answer. This makes it easier for others with similar problems to find it.